# android-support-v4 lib file, list of supported APIs?

Tags: android, api, android-support-library

I am working on simple app that will have media player and recorder. And I don't want my APK file to be too big. I have found android-support-v4.jar file in libs which takes about 700kb of memory and that is a lot. Now I read that it's a support library but where can I find list of APIs that this library support? I'd like to remove it but I don't want to cause some errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have found android-support-v4.jar file in libs which takes about
>   700kb of memory and that is a lot

Proguard can remove what it is not used, leaving just the class that you are using in your app,

> Now I read that it's a support library but where can I find list of
>   APIs that this library support?

I do think you can find the changelog file (README.txt) into `sdk/extras/android/support`